# TFS Code Review: Latest version of file with all changes included

Tags: c#, tfs, version-control

Say we have a file called `Person.cs`

We have a work item to make some changes to `Person.cs` 4321.

I make Changes to `Person.cs`and check that in against 4321, this creates a changeset of 123 against work item 4321.

I make another change to the file because I did't think if a usecase and we might have a bug. I check this one in against 4321, now we have a changeset 124  against work item 4321.

Little to be known, I have left some debugging code inside `Person.cs`, So I have to fix that, check that in  against work item 4321 and created changeset 125 against work item 4321.

This is a simple example, but you can probably see where I'm going with this.

When a code review is done, it would be nice to see the latest version with all changes to `Person.cs` in work item 4321 compared to the file before we started this work item.

Is there an extension for TFS that would do this?

When there are 20 changesets, it can get quite tedious when all you want to do is tell TFS to give you all changes made to a file for a particular work item.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you check in changesets 124 and 125, can you not check them in against work item 4321? Oh, nm, I misunderstood. You're checking them all in against 4321, but viewing the diff of latest shows you the diff of 125 and 124 rather than, say, 125 and 122. Is that it?

Comment: @wablab see my question updated, This is exactly what we do. and you are correct. Especially if you go online onto TFS it does not make it easy for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such extension by default.

You can achieve what you want by using TFS API. First, [get work item history](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx) to check which changsets this work item is linked to (in your example, the linked changesets are 123,124,125). Then, use [Difference Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/difference-command) to displays the differences between the changesets (compare changset 122 with changset 125).